# Application crash when application become active

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an iphone application. I am using XCode 3.2.3 and iphone SDK4.

Application is supporting multitasking as of every application built in this version of XCode. My application goes into background and become active without any problem. One thing worth nothing here is that I don't need to store any information which I need when application become active.

Right, here comes the real question. Application works If I don't drain off memory by playing other applications.

For example if I use my application and then use some game applications and then use my application it gives me memory warning level 1 and sometimes level 2 and crash.

Anyone any idea.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are referencing some objects that iOS decided to purge while your application was in the background.
Please try to locate where the application crashes and post this here some we may provide more detailed help. Otherwise it will just be guessing.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your response. I'll post the stack trace very soon because this is driving me crazy for a long time now.

Comment: @Claus: iOS does not decide to purge objects, you application does. iOS only sends a memory notification and the app responds accordingly. You're right that the problem is probably a reference to a released object.

Comment: Hi Guys, how can I run Zombie through instrument on my device? I am trying to find out the exact line where it is crashing?

Comment: Another update. I am using .NET web-service to get information from internet. I am declaring webData (NSMutableData) in web-service call like this

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
 
if( theConnection )
{
 webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}

webData gets released when OS receives memory warning and that's where it is crashing.

I forgot how do you run Zombie through instrument. If someone can help me out in this then I would be able to post some stack trace.

Thanks

Comment: @Nikolai: There are certain objects that iOS will purge for you in case memory gets tight. This includes for instance, non-visible UIViewController views, various cached datas such as those obtained through [UIImage imageNamed:], NSCache, etc. See Session 105 from WWDC 2010 for more details about this.

Comment: @Claus: The frameworks your application uses register for the notification and clean up some of their objects. But it's still your application that does this cleanup, not the OS, even though it might be in framework code. If frameworks decide to dump internal caches it should not be visible from the frameworks public API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, it sounds like you might release webData twice. Once during the normal clean-up and then in the clean-up due to low memory.

Ensure that you set the `webData` variable to nil after releasing it. That way it will be harmless to try to release it a second time. Alternatively you can access it through a property and then allocate it using `self.webData = [NSMutableData data]` and release it using `self.webData = nil`

Comment: Thanks Claus. Much appreciated.

You are absolutely right. I am releasing webData after connectionDidFinishLoading. What do you recommend in this situation? Should I do something like that 

[webData release];
self.webData = nil;

or should I do just
 
self.webData = nil;

Comment: That depends if you are using properties or not. If you are using properties, then self.webData = nil will do the trick. If you are not using properties then you need to set webData = nil after releasing it.

Comment: Hey Claus, Thanks. I am using properties. So I have changed my code accordingly from [webData release]; to self.webData = nil; I have installed the new app on my device. I'll test this throughout the day tomorrow. I'll let you know if I get any issues. Thanks once again. I'll mark the question as answered tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger to find out more about the crash. The stack trace shows you the place incode where the crash happens.

You can simulate a low memory condition in the simulator using the menu.